# Is it possible to move .mx file from one server to other?

Tags: export, import, interoperability

I have mathematica file in one server along with `.mx` file. Is there any way to move the `.mx` file from one server to other such that the values can be regained in other server?

Is an `.mx` file exported on one computer readable on other computers?

Comment: Yes, but only if you have the same version of Mathematica and the same system (e.g. Linux 64-bit). In general, mx files are not portable.

Comment: @ybeltukov Since Mathematica 10 it is possible to move .mx files fom one server to the other, also from Windows to Linux etc.

Comment: @RolfMertig Good news, thanks!

Comment: @RolfMertig could you please elaborate on this (maybe in an answer) as I cannot find info on this in the Documentation. It says there that transfer between OS is not possible.

Comment: @Thomas The documentation is outdated, but Wolfram support confirmed this to be a new feature of Mathematica 10.

Answer (score 9):

Starting with Mathematica 10, `.mx` files are only restricted by 'bitness', i.e. an `.mx` file generated on a 64 bit machine should be interchangeable between all 64 bit platforms (Windows-x86-64, OSX-x86-64, Linux-x86-64). Similarly, MX files generated on 32 bit platforms should be compatible with Windows-x86 and Linux-x86.

Comment: Would you happen to have any reference for that, e.g. in the online help? The .mx documentation seems a bit sparse.

Comment: @YvesKlett Not sure about the documentation but support has confirmed this to me.  The documentation still claim otherwise, "MX files cannot be exchanged between different operating systems or versions of the Wolfram System.", but I believe this to be an error.

Comment: @YvesKlett I think it shouldn't be a problem if I share [the email](http://pastebin.com/SkBCGaNY) I got from support ...

Comment: The documentation indeed doesn't reflect this. It will be fixed in the next release.

Comment: @Szabolcs thanks!